# Communication between application layers in C# WPF with Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, caliburn.micro, eventaggregator

I'm building an n-tier, client/server application with C# and WPF (WCF for client/server communications)

What I'd like to be able to do is have my client side service managers be able to push data straight to a ViewModel, and in so doing, have it hit the view.

For example: 
User A has the application open, and has the CustomersViewModel open showing a list of customers.

User B adds a new customer to the database.

At the point where the repository knows the data from User B has been saved, I want to push a message out to all connected clients (NotifyClientsOfUpdateMessage). When the client side service manager receives this message, I want to use something like the Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator to then push that out to any ViewModel that implements IHandle to display a message in the view stating that the list has changed, click update to refresh.

Now - to my questions.
1 - Can the Caliburn.Micro EventAggregator communicate between layers of the application? In my Autofac container, the EventAggregator is registered as a single instance shared between the application layer (ViewModels) and the Client layer which houses all the client side Proxies, managers etc.

Essentially I'd like to publish an event from the client manager up to the application layer and having the ViewModels handle that information however required. Is this possible?

2 - Is There a more efficient way of achieving this same behavior?

Please forgive me if this is a basic question, this is my first client-server application and I'm 1 year into teaching myself to write apps. I have done numerous searches through google, SO, MSDN etc and can not find any information about this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is what the aggregator was built for. however that is within a single application. If the application is a distributed system you will need an external system to handle the communication between the distributed applications. something like a messaging queue or pub sub  system (think SignalR) that can handle that requirement and then when an application receives a message it hands the responsibility off to the event aggregator.

Comment: If you are using WCF, you can have a look at Callback Contract. It will help to to send your notification to the connected clients. Sample is here https://www.codeproject.com/articles/660479/duplex-service-in-wcf

Comment: Thanks for the responses. 

Currently my server has no understanding of connected clients, IP Addresses etc. Until the application knows who is connected and what IP they are connecting in on, there is no way I can see for me to publish a message to all connected clients.. 

I'm re-jigging the server application now to have a list of connected client sockets so that I can get the IP 's and push out the required messages.. 

Thanks again, I appreciate you both taking the time to shed some light on this for me...